# Intervals from an underdetermined nonnegative linear system

Tags: causality, geometry, convex

I'm working on a problem in genomics that yields the following puzzle. Let $b\in \mathbb R^I$, $t$ and $p\in \mathbb R^J$, and $s \in \mathbb R^{I\times J}$. Suppose $t,b,p$ are known. Further suppose:

- $t_j = \sum_i s_{ij}$
- $b_i = \sum_j p_j s_{ij}$
- $s_{ij} > 0$

What's a simple, efficient way to infer, for all $i$, $j$, the narrowest interval $[\ell_{ij}, u_{ij}]$ that is guaranteed to contain $s_{ij}$?

$I$ and $J$ will both be at most dozens and often much less, but I will want to repeat this hundreds of thousands of times.

I tagged this as causal statistics even though it's not causal statistics because I know that very similar problems arise in the binary instrumental variable model when bounding the average causal effect.

Answer (score 1):

The set of $s$'s that fit the data is a polytope, and finding the intervals you described is the same as projecting the polytope onto each coordinate axis. Polytope projection is described on [this lovely page](https://scaron.info/teaching/projecting-polytopes.html) with lots of algorithmic options. One possible solution is to find the vertices, project them, and take the max and min.

The abstract of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.4150.pdf) suggests that you can't do any better than vertex enumeration in many cases. Your input is in $H$-representation (it's intersection of half-spaces), and the output can be in any representation, since it's so simple. Your target subspace is not degenerate, so according to table 2 of the paper, your problem is "VE-hard", i.e. at least as hard as vertex enumeration.

So, follow the first link and figure out the "plumbing", e.g. the values of $A$, $b$, $C$, $d$, and $x$ in terms of your $b$, $t$, $p$ and $s$. (Hint: your $s$ gets vectorized into $x$. Sums and weighted sums are implemented by entries of $C$, which will depend on your $p$. $A$ is negative identity and $b$ is 0. $d$ contains your $b$ and $t$.

Comment: Can anyone verify that vertex enumeration is a reasonable thing to do??